# getting data from web service flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

am learning flutter right now .. and am trying to retrive some data from web service and display it in a list ...

and am doing it like this:

```
getcompanies() async {
var url = 'my link';
http.post(url, body: json.encode({'token': globals.token})).then((response) {
// print("Response body: ${response.body}");
Map data = json.decode(response.body);
final companies =
    (data['Companies'] as List).map((i) => new Company.fromJson(i));
for (final company in companies) {
  if (!company.category.contains("الراعي") &&
      !company.category.contains("الشريك") &&
      !company.category.contains("الداعم")) {
    if (company.logo != "") {
      names.add(company.name);
      logos.add(company.logo);
    }
  }
}
 });
}

class Company {
 String name;
 String category;
 String logo;

Company.fromJson(Map json) {
this.name = json['Name'];
this.category = json['Category'];
this.logo = json['Logo'];
}
}

// Home page...
class CompaniesPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
return new _CompaniesPageState();
}
}

class _CompaniesPageState extends State<CompaniesPage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
getcompanies();
return new Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  child: new Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Color(0xFF49C275)),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: Text(
        'الشركات',
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Color(0xFF49C275),
          fontSize: 18.0,
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        // action button
        IconButton(
          icon: new Image.asset(
            'assets/images/searchicon.png',
            width: 19.0,
            height: 19.0,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    ),
    drawer: new Drawer(
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new DrawerHeader(
            child: new Image.asset(
              'assets/images/logo.png',
              height: 149.0,
              width: 149.0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text('الرئيسية'),
            onTap: () {
              homePage();
            },
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text('الشركات'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text('الرعاة'),
            onTap: () {
              sponsersPage();
            },
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text('حسابي'),
            onTap: () {
              myaccountPage();
            },
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text('كودي'),
            onTap: () {
              myqrPage();
            },
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text('من نحن'),
            onTap: () {
              aboutusPage();
            },
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text('تواصل معنا'),
            onTap: () {
              contactusPage();
            },
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text('تسجيل خروج'),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text('English'),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    body: new Padding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
      child: new Center(
        child: new ListView(
          children: createCompaniesChildren(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}

 List<Widget> createCompaniesChildren() {
 List<Widget> children = List<Widget>();
 for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  children.add(
    new Padding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, left: 15.0),
      child: new Image.network(
        logos[i],
        width: 346.0,
        height: 180.0,
      ),
    ),
  );
  children.add(
    new Padding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, left: 15.0),
      child: new Center(
        child: new Text(
          names[i],
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 17.0),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  children.add(new Divider());
  }
  return children;
  }
```

this is retrieving and everything .. but it doesn't display it until i go to another page and then come back to this page i can see the list .. otherwise when first open is empty ...

how to solve this? i want the list to be displayed as soon the page is launched...

tried doing this:

```
getcompanies() async {
var url = 'my link';
http
    .post(url, body: json.encode({'token': globals.token}))
    .then((response) {
  // print("Response body: ${response.body}");
  Map data = json.decode(response.body);
  final companies =
  (data['Companies'] as List).map((i) => new Company.fromJson(i));
  setState(() {
    for (final company in companies) {
      if (!company.category.contains("الراعي") &&
          !company.category.contains("الشريك") &&
          !company.category.contains("الداعم")) {
        if (company.logo != "") {
          names.add(company.name);
          logos.add(company.logo);
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
}
```

and now it's working fine as i want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not telling flutter to re-build the widget after you retrieve the data from your server.

you may need to add

```
setState(() { for (final company in companies) { ..... }})
```

setState will trigger the widget to rebuild.

First when the widget is built your **names** list is empty so that only your listview is empty after you fill the list with server data you need to call setState to tell widget to rebuild.

Comment: am getting errors with the ) and } .. can you give me the whole method please

Answer (score 0):

call `setState()` method after you are done updating your list.
This method will automatically render your screen.

Aaaaaand don't forget to put the method `getCompanies()` inside your `StatefulWidget` i.e. `_CompaniesPageState`

```
class _CompaniesPageState extends State<CompaniesPage> {
    getcompanies() async {
     var url = 'my link';
     http.post(url, body: json.encode({
      'token': globals.token
     })).then((response) {
      // print("Response body: ${response.body}");
      Map data = json.decode(response.body);
      final companies =
       (data['Companies'] as List).map((i) => new Company.fromJson(i));
      for (final company in companies) {
       if (!company.category.contains("الراعي") &&
        !company.category.contains("الشريك") &&
        !company.category.contains("الداعم")) {
        if (company.logo != "") {
         names.add(company.name);
         logos.add(company.logo);
        }
       }
      }
      //*here*
      setState(() -> {});
     });
    }
    @override 
    Widget build(context) {
        ....
    }
  }
```

The method `setState()` is inherited from `State` class.

Comment: i got: the method setState is not defined

Comment: okay solved the above error .. but now i got: setstate expected an identifier

Comment: Put the method getCompanies() inside your StatefulWidget

Comment: i did and am getting this error: setstate expected an identifier

Comment: thank you so much for the help! the updated part in my post is the one worked with me ..